# Где я делаю ошибку в запросе к api kaspi.kz?

Tags: python, api, requests

Мне необходимо получить список отзывов , чтобы в дальнейшем их интегрировать в сайт, но у меня этого сделать не получается и я не могу понять почему. Kaspi дает документацию и я следую по ней,как мне кажется, но ответ не получаю.

Ниже оставлю ссылку на документацию, скрин конкретного фрагмента документации и свой код.

1. https://kaspi.kz/merchantcabinet/support/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=917615#API%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4
2. [image: Элемент списка]

3. 

```py
import datetime

# Временные метки для указанных дат в миллисекундах
start_date = datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 10)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 10)
start_timestamp = int(start_date.timestamp() * 1000)
end_timestamp = int(end_date.timestamp() * 1000)

print("Временная метка начала периода:", start_timestamp)
print("Временная метка конца периода:", end_timestamp)

import requests


url = "https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/merchantreviews/"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "X-Auth-Token": "token"  #  токен аутентификации
}
params = {
    "page[number]": 0,
    "page[size]": 20,
    "filter[merchantreviews][approvedDate][$ge]": start_timestamp,
    "filter[merchantreviews][approvedDate][$le]": end_timestamp,
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params , timeout=3)
print(response.status_code)
```